# Javascript (Not for Web) need to replace all offending characters

Tags: javascript

I am writing javascript for an application that allows this kind of scripting to expand its own functionality. (Esko) This is NOT for the web. I have various text strings with various undesirable characters that I need to replace. What I have works for everything except a double quote. This is what I have:

```
function f ()
  {
//Remove Illegal characters and replace with an underscore
//List of Illegal chars
var re = /[\*\"\%\'\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\{\}\[\]\(\)[\]]/gi;
var str = "SANTA FE NATURAL TOBACCO COMPA"NY INC %#$%^ American Spirit";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "");
//Remove double underscores
var re = /_+/g;
var str = newstr;
var newstr = str.replace(re, '_');
return (newstr)
  }
f ();
```

The var str changes with every order, so its always different.
I can change the var str line to read:
var str = 'SANTA FE NATURAL TOBACCO COMPA"NY INC %#$%^ American Spirit'; (single quotes)
and I can get the double quotes replaced, but not the singles. I need both gone. How can I accomplish??

My experience with JS is very limited, be gentle.

Thanks

Comment: You need to start with a properly escaped input `str`. Where do the values come from? Are they inserted in the script source, or are they read in by the script itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your code eliminates the `"` when I run it in my console, except that I had to escape it (`\"`) in the definition of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The minute you think to yourself "This can be solved by a regular expression", you now have two problems.

You should make use of the following two functions:

var encoded = encodeURIcomponent('SANTA FE NATURAL TOBACCO COMPA"NY INC %#$%^ American Spirit');

var decoded = decodeURIcomponent(encoded);

Unless you are handling these with node.js then it might be best to make use of buffers.

var encoded = new Buffer('SANTA FE NATURAL TOBACCO COMPA"NY INC %#$%^ American Spirit');

encoded.toString();

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine; the problem is that you didn't input `str` correctly. When you write literal `'` strings, you *must* escape `'`s in your string; likewise for `"` strings. This is unavoidable when hardcoding strings into your code. To enter these strings without escaping any characters, read `str` from the user instead of writing it into the source.